# Upgrade failing from windows sharepoint server (WSS) 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: windows, sharepoint

I'm doing an inplace upgrade from wss 2.0 to 3.0. I have passed pre-upgrade scan.  I then install WSS 3.0 which kicks off the upgrade.  The upgrade fails and in the Upgrade.log it has this stack trace below.  This seemed like a time out error so I increased the timeout to unlimited in sqlserver. I then initiated the migration from command prompt again with the following code:

```
   psconfig –cmd upgrade –inplace v2v –wait –force
```

I received the same errors below again:

[SPManager] [ERROR] [8/4/2009 3:09:43 PM]:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseSequence.ExecuteDataDefinitionMethodCore(SqlSession sqlSession, ISqlSession isqlSession, String sqlscript, SPSqlCommandFactory sqlcmdFactory, String[] strTables, Int32[] nThroughputs, SPLog logGlobal)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseSequence.ExecuteDataDefinitionMethod(SqlSession sqlSession, String sqlscript, SPLog log)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.Upgrade()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)

Please let me know if you have a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: There should be a better log available than this. Have you checked the SQL log, Windows Event Viewer, SharePoint ULS logs? If so please update your question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen Joel Oleson's [5 Reasons NOT to Use In Place Upgrade](http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/archive/2007/04/30/5-reasons-not-to-use-in-place-upgrade.aspx)?

Joel managed the biggest SharePoint Deployment, Microsoft's. I would take his word for it. There are plenty of third party tools to help you migrate data to a clean install.

Metalogix and Tzunami are the highest rated migration tools on SharePointReviews.com